# Best practice for deployment of C program with libraries on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu

I've written a program that incorporates the MariaDB C connector library to connect and interact with MariaDB.  I followed the steps from the MariaDB website, basically:

1. install the connector from a terminal with `sudo apt install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev`
2. add `#include <mysql.h`> to the C or C++ file that wants to talk to MariaDB
3. add a reference to my build command such as this: `gcc -o program main.c $(mariadb_config --include --libs)`

This worked great. But I just followed instructions, and lack some of the underlying knowledge such as

- where on the ubuntu machine is `libmariadb3` placed?
- how is my program finding it?
- (most importantly) which parts of the `libmariadb3` library do I need to deploy (run, not build) on a different machine, and what is the best way to do that?

This last one is the big one; what's the simplest professional way to deploy a small simple application to a target Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Perhaps you want your package manager to take care of that. For deployment on Ubuntu machines, build a .deb package and correctly specify its dependence on mariadb (and anything else you might need). When the package gets installed, it will pull the dependencies (including mariadb) and install them in a standard place where all programs can find it.

Comment: You might be interested to see what `mariadb_config --include --libs` is outputting.

Comment: git submodules is really useful if you're integrating third party libraries into your project. Each OS can then individually clone and compile the necessary libraries needed for compilation.

Comment: What is the output of `mariadb_config --include --libs`? It will probably reveal a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where on the ubuntu machine is `libmariadb3` placed?

In `sudo apt install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev`, you are installing libraries. I'd guess the dynamic shared object `.so` libraries and static `.a` libraries are in places like `/usr/lib`. Header files which go along with these libraries are probably in `/usr/include`. Dig around there and tell us what you find.

Run `dpkg -L libmariadb3` and `dpkg -L libmariadb-dev` to see where they are installed. Add the output to the bottom of your question.

`apt list --installed` can list all installed packages, in case you ever need to inspect other packages with `dpkg -L <name>`, but don't know the `<name>` part.

> how is my program finding it?

From your `gcc` build command, I can see that you have some command substitution going on with `$()`. The `mariadb_config --include --libs` command should include a list of libraries to include, I think. Tell us what your output is.

Those libraries will be in `/usr/lib`, I think.

What is the output of `mariadb_config --include --libs` and `dpkg -L libmariadb3` and `dpkg -L libmariadb-dev`?

> (most importantly) which parts of the `libmariadb3` library do I need to deploy (run, not build) on a different machine?

I'm not 100% sure, but I think they will need the same libraries and headers that you have. Maybe they need fewer, but having the same ones you have wouldn't hurt, I suppose.

> ...and what is the best way to do that?
>
> what's the simplest professional way to deploy a small simple application to a target Ubuntu machine?

I have no idea to get something into the `apt` package manager so that they can just run `sudo apt install whatever`.

In my experience on Ubuntu thus far, I'd say you have 3 great options outside of this:

1. Option 1: Build the application for Ubuntu yourself, and just give us the executables and the commands to run to install the dependencies. We run the commands to install dependencies and then we just move the executable into `/usr/bin/` so we can use it. Even better, we put it into `~/bin` so it doesn't clutter `/usr/bin`. We then have to add `~/bin` to our PATH, which Ubuntu automatically does for us in our `~/.profile` file if we just close and reopen all terminals after creating the `~/bin` dir for the first time. You could put the executable into a GitHub "release" on your GitHub page, for us to download it.
2. Option 2: you give us excellent build-from-source instructions, and we build from source. This is a common style on many gnu programs:

   ```bash
   wget some_package.tar.gz
   tar -xf some_package.tar.gz  # unzip it
   cd some_package
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

   But so long as it works, I don't care what your build commands look like.
3. Option 3: you wrap everything up into an installation bash script, and we just download and run it in a single command like this:

   ```bash
   curl -L https://some_github_path | /bin/bash
   ```

   Example of this: https://github.com/nicolargo/glances#glances-auto-install-script-the-easy-way (granted, this is a Python program, but the concept is the same)

   Whether this option 3 does Option 1 or 2 under-the-hood is up to you.

   Another similar example is here: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#using-git. The point is: we run an install script.

   Yet another really nice example: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/BrosTrendWifiAdapterSoftware:

   ```bash
   sh -c 'busybox wget deb.trendtechcn.com/install -O /tmp/install && sh /tmp/install'
   ```

Note: in any of the options above, if you want a nice GUI launcher button we can click to launch the new program you just gave us, you'll need to add a .desktop file to `/usr/share/applications/` or `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` for us. See [Ask Ubuntu: Where are the .desktop icon files stored?](https://askubuntu.com/a/217339/327339).

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer Gabriel!  I'll be studying it over the next couple of days, learn everything I can.

Comment: @Chris, glad to help. In addition to consulting Stack Overflow, I also recommend you chat with AIs such as Bing Chat, GitHub Copilot, ChatGPT, and Google Bard. They are very helpful. Be sure to check everything and not accept it all as truth, but they are very useful in making you aware of tools and options and what to try next, and how.

Comment: Development was slow, just now ready to digest and decide on these options.  Thank you again for the beautiful answer(s).

Comment: @Chris, I'd love to hear and see what you come up with. Post a link if it's public, when you get it done.